# convert object json to object vb .net

Tags: json, vb.net

Hello I need to convert this objetct to vb.

```
{"user": 
 [
  {"name":"CompanyName"},
  {"password":"CompanyPassword"},
  {"email":"mail@company.com"},
  {"name":"UserName"},
  {"email":"user@mail.com"}
 ]
}
```

I try with this:

```
Public Class InfoObjUser
 Public Property name As String
 Public Property password As String
 Public Property email As String
End Class

Public Class ObjUser
 Public Property user As New List(Of InfoObjUser)
End Class
```

but when I go to serialize json object created in vb
I see that there are no curly brackets. 
Also in vb I can't add {"name":"UserName"},{"email":"user@mail.com"}
because they are already present.

Comment: show your code which you try to serialize also include the code you try to add name and email. please edit the question and include the code samples.

Comment: Take a look at [json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: That class does not quite match the J string.  One Email property cant hold 2 different email values.  Without code showing what you are doing and how, it is hard to help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [JSON Serialization in .Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You need to add the System.Runtime.Serialization as reference to your project, and then set up a serializer object in your code. You also need to tag, which fields in your class match your JSON code.

This would be your class setup:

```
<DataContract>
Public Class InfoObjUser
 <DataMember(Name:="Name")>
 Public Property name As String
 <DataMember(Name:="Password")>
 Public Property password As String
 <DataMember(Name:="Email")>
 Public Property email As String
End Class

<DataContract>
Public Class ObjUser
 <DataMember>
 Public Property user As New List(Of InfoObjUser)
End Class
```

And a Json reader class for that would look like this:

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Json

Public Class JsonReader

  Public Shared Function FromString(Of T)(ByVal input As String) As T
    Dim serializer As New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(T))
    Dim memStream As New MemoryStream()

    Dim sw As New StreamWriter(memStream)
    sw.Write(input)
    sw.Flush()

    memStream.Position = 0

    Dim returnObj As T = CType(serializer.ReadObject(memStream), T)
    Return returnObj
  End Function

End Class
```

And finally, you can call this class like this:

```
Dim jsonString ' = ...Input string here
Dim user As ObjUser = JsonReader.FromString(Of ObjUser)(jsonString)
```

However, it is not possible to have the name for two different data objects, as the serializer would not know where to map them to, as it goes by Object name.

I don't know how established this data structure already is, but if it's possible, I would suggest you to change the duplicated names, as no real mapping can occur when doing so programmatically.

```
 <DataMember(Name:="UserName")>
 Public Property username As String
 <DataMember(Name:="UserEmail")>
 Public Property usermail As String
```

If you would add something like this to your data model class and rename the field names in your Json, then it would work.